# PHP snmpwalk(): No response, working via putty

Tags: php, centos, snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to get values from a device. It worked well & gave the results when I was running the snmp via putty. The command goes like this.

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 1.2.3.4 1.5.2.33.1.4.2.2.1.1
```

But when put in php & ran it, it gave this:

> Warning: snmpwalk(): No response from 1.2.3.4

I've read some articles and said to update the snmp in the server (Centos). I did that, but the result still same.
I also tried to change `snmpwalk` with `snmp2_walk` and `snmpwalkoid`. Still not work.
Anyone can help? Thanks for all your kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention the device IP address which you are going to make SNMP query.

```
Warning: snmpwalk(): No response from 1.2.3.4
```

The above error says , SNMP tries to query the host 1.2.3.4 and it fails.
The correct syntax is

```
snmpwalk -v 2c localhost -c public 1.2.3.4 1.5.2.33.1.4.2.2.1.1
```

Comment: Well thanks.
Yes, I did. `1.2.3.4` was just an IP example and the rest right is the OID. When I ping the real IP, it works. And also ran the whole syntax above it works on putty, but did work on php.
Thanks before for your kindness.